# Python pandas-automating excel sheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, list, numpy

How can I take the maximum value of three consecutive rows in a particular column iteratively in a spreadsheet using python pandas. For example, first I have to take the maximum of 0th row to the 2nd row, then from 3rd row to the 5th row

Comment: Have you already imported the excel file to a `pandas` dataframe? What have you done?

Comment: @rasini  Can you please give the example what you are trying to achieve and what have to done so far to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

From next time onwards, please make sure to post  in your question what you have done to attempt a solution.

Assuming s.csv contains your data frame.. 
f returns the column given its index.
g returns what you want - the maximum of elements taken 3 at a time from top to bottom in the column.

```
        d=pd.read_csv("s.csv")

        >>> d
          a   b  c
      0   6  12  3
      1   2   1  5
      2   7  13  1
      3   4   2  2
      4  23   4  9
      5   4   1  1

        f=lambda j: list(d.iloc[:,j])
        g=lambda col: [max(col[i],col[i+1],col[i+2]) for i in range(0,len(col),3)]
        >>> g(f(0))
          [7, 23]
        >>> g(f(1))
          [13, 4]
        >>> g(f(2))
          [5, 9]
```